# SOAP Error "iaik.security.ssl.SSLException: Peer sent alert: Alert Fatal: handshake failure" in webMethods 6.5

Tags: soap, tls1.2, sslhandshakeexception, webmethods, sslexception

I have encountered the below error while executing the pub.client:soapHTTP service that is available in WmPublic.

> java.io.IOException: said.security.ssl.SSLException: Peer sent alert: Alert Fatal: handshake failure

On further investigation, I found that TLSv1.2 is being used by the partner server and I believe wM 6.5 only supports TLS v1.0. This might be a TLS version issue.

I am using webMethods 6.5.
Trusted Certificates > CA Certificate Directory is unspecified and watt.security.cert.wmChainVerifier.trustByDefault is set as TRUE for my server. Therefore, all CAs should be trusted.

**Is there any way to make this work as upgrading wM is not an option, unfortunately?**

I found this page (link PFB) where there is a section called TLS/SSL Handshake Issues & Debugging. There my handshake issue is mentioned and as a solution, it said:

> handshake failed as Integration Server using Entrust IAIK connects to a TLS 1.2 enabled server. In this case, change from IAIK to JSSE option and set "watt.net.jsse.client.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2"

I tried the above way but it did not work and yes, I restarted the server after changing the configuration.
Moreover, it also stated that

> For outbound SSL connection (i.e. Integration Server is acting as SSL client), the following watt properties control the protocol version and ciphersuites:
>
> > IAIK:watt.net.ssl.client.handshake.minVersion,watt.net.ssl.client.handshake.maxVersion, watt.net.ssl.client.strongcipheronly,watt.net.ssl.client.cipherSuiteList
> >
> > JSSE:watt.net.jsse.client.enabledProtocols,watt.net.jsse.client.enabledCipherSuiteList.

But I don't have any of those parameters configured in server.cnf and even if I had to I don't know what values I should configure them with. I'd like some help with those if it'll help with the situation.

https://techcommunity.softwareag.com/pwiki/-/wiki/Main/Debugging%20TLS%20SSL%20connections%20in%20Integration%20Server

Answer (score 0):

try to set in extended settings

```
watt.net.ssl.client.useJSSE=true
```

i dont know the old version but it could be that the `useJsse` parameter that normally is set on the .`http` and .`soapClient` service is just taken from the default properties